# jQuery version of simple javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in javascript

```
var greet;

greet = function() {
  var textoNombre;
  textoNombre = document.getElementById("textoNombre");
  return alert(textoNombre.value);
};
```

what is working on the HTML document. But if I change `document.getElementById("textoNombre")` by the jQuery version `$("#textoNombre")` it just dont work. The alert says "undefined".

I have the jQuery script linked on the head of the HTML before to my custom js file.

This is a very basic question but I tried different things and no one work, can you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is not a jquery  this is a pure javascript

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, then I cant call the jQuery functions on normal javascript code?

Comment: your code can work https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/k6e7cL67/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because jQuery objects don't have a `value` property, the equivelant is `$('#someId').val()`.

To get the underlying DOM object, you can use `$('#someId')[0]`. This is because jQuery objects are actually like arrays, and their elements are the DOM objects themselves. That means `$('#someId')[0].value` would work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery objects are not DOM objects and don't share all their properties.

To get the current value of a form control, you would use [the `.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/), not the `.value` property.

Comment: Thank you very much... I know this is a completely newby question :S